# Can't connect to local computer via SQL Server 2008 Express Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms, sql-server-2008-express

HI, folks,

Previously, I had a SQL Server 2008 installed, but then I deleted it, and installed SQL Server 2008 Express Management Studio. And now I can't connect to local computer. I get error :

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occured while establishing a
>   connection to SQL server. The server
>   was not found or was not
>   accesible.Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQl Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections.(provide: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error:40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 2).

But I can create DB via VS2010.

Comment: I believe express editions run a named instance.  You are specifying it in your connection string, right?  Something like, (local)\SQLEXPRESS or 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS?

Comment: Thank, this helped. 
 Only i need specify (local)\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Had the same problem and Mark's comment was the solution as well. Probably should be made into an full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of Mark's comment:

I believe express editions run a named instance. You are specifying it in your connection string, right? Something like, (local)\SQLEXPRESS or 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS?

From Microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165679(v=sql.90).aspx:

SQL Server Express is typically installed as a named instance. The default name of the instance is SQLExpress.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Express editions install by default without TCP/IP connectivity.  If your database service is running on one compute and the management studio is on another, you will need to enable TCP/IP using the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in:

File - Connect Object Explorer - Server name: - Network Servers - Database Engine - here would be your database name/database instance(use this or select it)

[image]

In my case it was different from computer name, therefore there wasn't any result with Windows Authentication, when I've tried to see the list of databases.